# How to send some parameter(dynamic path) from mapDispatchToProps to the watcherSaga/workingSaga (middleware)?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I just want to send some extra parameters when there is an action call "GET_NODES_ASYNC", I need to send the path along with it so that this path could be sent to the workingSaga for API call via watcherSaga. But I am not able to send it to my watcherSaga properly

```
// reactComponent.js

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        reduxGetNodes: path =>
          dispatch({
            type: "GET_NODES_ASYNC",
            path: "article/path/"   // It comes from an dynamic react component
          })
      };
    };

// watcherSaga.js

    export function* watchNodes(path) {      
          console.log("*******  " + path);       // It comes undefined here  
          yield takeLatest("GET_NODES_ASYNC", nodesAsync, path);
    }
```

The path was not passed properly from mapDispatchToProps to watcherSaga and thus path = "undefined" on console.log(). Instead, I need it to be "article/pathHere/"

Answer (score 1):

`mapDispatchToProps` has access to component props as second argument. So it should look something like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    reduxGetNodes: () => {
      const { path } = ownProps;
      dispatch({
        type: "GET_NODES_ASYNC",
        path
      });
    }
  };
};

function* nodeAsync(action) {
    console.log("*******  " + action.path);  
    ...
}

export function* watchNodes() {      
  yield takeLatest("GET_NODES_ASYNC", nodeAsync);
}
```